# What is the correct structure for sulfur dioxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds, lewis-structure, erratum

A question from the National Chemistry Olympiad (Germany-2008) goes as follows:

> Besides the composition of a substance the structure of its molecule or ion is of interest. To predict the structure you may use the electron repulsion theory
>   (VSEPR).
>   The following sulphur compounds are choosen as examples
>   $\ce{SO2}$, $\ce{SO3(g)}$, $\ce{SOF2}$, $\ce{SO4^2-}$, $\ce{SF4}$, $\ce{SOF4}$, $\ce{SF6}$.
>
> b) Draw the structure of these species. Insert the free electron pairs of $\ce{S}$.
>   Give the name of the geometrical shape of these compounds or ions.

I'm only interested in the structure of $\ce{SO2}$, that is represented in the answer sheet as $\ce{O=S-O}$ instead of the one I believe is the correct one $\ce{O=S=O}$.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_dioxide#Structure_and_bonding).
It's because it can be thought as two interchangeable resonant structures. What happens in reality is that the electron is delocalized over the three atoms.

[image]